Calculating effect size
We have conducted a systematic review to investigate the effectiveness of a treatment for a psychological disorder. We aim to report effect sizes and p values of the reviewed studies but one study has only reported CI 95, p value and t score regarding the effect of the treatment between baseline and post-treatment. Given that the used t test was from a paired t test, is it possible to determine the the Cohen's d based on the available information?
I'd very much appreciate it if you help me with this problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to Cross Validated! How precise is the given p-value? Is it given as a long decimal, or is it given as something more like < 0.05 or < 0.01?

I would approach the problem as follows.

The midpoint of the confidence interval is the point estimate.

The width of the confidence interval is related to the sample size and the variance.

The particular t-stat along with the sample size gives the p-value. Given that you know the p-value, you can do some simulations to determine which sample size gives a p-value for the given t-stat.


tstat <- qt(0.99, 27)
p <- 0.01
diffs <- rep(NA, 100)
for (i in 1:100){
  
  diffs[i] <- abs(p - (1 - pt(tstat, i)))
  
}
which(diffs == min(diffs)) # Bingo, this returns that the 
                           # degrees of freedom was 27,
                           # which is corect

This returns 27 degrees of freedom, so you know the sample size was 28. Modify this code as appropriate for the two-sided test that I suspect was used.

You now have the sample size and the confidence interval width, so you can use these to calculate the variance.

Given the raw effect size and the standard deviation, I believe that is what you need to calculate Cohen's d.



+1. Just a small aside: instead of a loop, one could use the optimize function in R to find the minimum, e.g. for searching over the range c(1, 27) with the tstat and p variables you defined: optimize(function(i) {abs(p - (1 - pt(tstat, i)))}, c(1, 27)). Not more efficient than your example, but it might be faster in other situations, for example if you search over a much larger range. Anyway, I find that your example with the for loop is better to explain how to solve the problem described in the original question.
